# What would be a good approach to check a lot of websites if they have a code installed?

Tags: regex, curl, cron

This is more like a strategy question:

I need to check regularly a long list of websites if they have a code installed. I can't check all of them once. How to do it? I have PHP on my server.

Should I use cURL and regex? or file_get_contents()?

Comment: What do you mean by "have a code installed"?  How would you check whether a single website has "a code" installed?

Comment: I want to check if they have a snippet of code in their source. Something that looks similar to google analytics tracking code.

Comment: **-1** for being unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use cron jobs  (  http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/ )

1. First create a table in a database that will keep track when the latest "check" has occurred for each website ( use unix time ).
2. Figure out how many  website "checks" you want each time you run the cron job ( let's say 10 ).
3. Create a php script that gathers the 10 oldest "checked" websites and use curl to check those websites.
4. update the table with the current "checked" time for each website.
5. figure out how often this php script has to run to update the whole list.
   Let's say you have 100 websites and you want ALL these sites to be updated every hour.Each time the cron job runs it will check 10 websites. Then this cron-job has to run at least 10 x an hour to accomplish the job....

This will create a loop on all the websites but will limit each request. 
You have to do some trial test to see how many websites you can check every time and then implement this with a cron-job...

Good luck!

Comment: This is helpful. I like the idea of checking them by a number each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think either one is fine. To make sure the code actually runs though, and assuming you have some control over the code installed, just make sure the code requests something on your server, then you can have PHP launch a browser window that hits the website, and then wait for the request.

Answer (score 0):

I've did the following, based on @Paolo_NL_FR answer.

1. added a flag is_live for each item, default 0
2. added last_check (date) for each item
3. create a file that checks latest 10 sites based on last_check date
4. for each item checking is done through cURL, with a regular expression
5. after checking I'm marking items as live or not
6. add a cron to run the file daily

If you have 100 items to check, every item will be checked every 10 days. If you want more often you have multiple choices:
- you run the cron twice a day, every 6 hours etc
- you check more than 10 sites every run

That's it. Cool, thanks guys!